# serialize json object with classmethods

Tags: python, json

I have an object that looks like this

```
import json
from typing import Any

class Identity:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

class BasicEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj: Any) -> Any:
        return obj.__dict__
        
id = Identity(name='Random name')
print(json.dumps(id, cls=BasicEncoder))
```

This worked fine.

I decided to add `classmethod` functions to `Identity` object in order to have something like static methods that would allow to serialize the current object to json.

I changed the code to this

```
from __future__ import annotations
import json
from typing import Any

class Identity:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.permissions = []

    @classmethod
    def to_json(cls: Identity) -> str:
        return json.dumps(cls, cls=BasicEncoder)

class BasicEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj: Any) -> Any:
        return obj.__dict__
    
id = Identity(name='Random name')
print(id.to_json())
```

But now serialization throws this error

```
'mappingproxy' object has no attribute '__dict__'. Did you mean: '__dir__'
```

In a similar scenario (for another but more complex object) I got another exception

```
'getset_descriptor' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

What it is the problem? As far as I understand, it is trying to serialize more than just object fields now with `classmethod`. How to solve it?

I tried adding filtering for `__dict__` keys and values for `classmethod` encoder etc. but it did not help.

Comment: Because `to_json` is a class method, it'll receive the class object `Identity`; not the instance which actually has any data. In fact, the correct type annotation would be `def to_json(cls: Type[Identity])`…

Comment: Concert the mapping proxy to a `dict`

Comment: Oh, I did not realize that I had only instance there and thought I was passing the object. In that case I will just remove "classmethod" and pass self is it will work.

Comment: Python does support `@staticmethod` just in case. But regardless whether you use `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod`, so long as the intended function of to_json is to serialize an instance of Identity then you need to pass the object as the input.

Answer (score 2):

First, I am a little confused about the context of the question: it doesn't seem to be clear that whether you are asking about the behavior of custom `JSONEncoder` or you have some generic misunderstanding about classmethod/instances which therefore makes you ask the wrong question: what's the point of using classmethod here? You are invoking the classmethod from the instances and it appears you are trying to serialize the class Identity rather than the instance `id` itself. Note that changing the code as shown in your example does not do the "***that would allow to serialize the current object to json***" you mentioned.

Then talking about your custom JSONEncoder `BasicEncoder` itself. If you look into the built-in `class JSONEncoder`, then you will see that  your custom encoder attempts to iteratively encode the `id.__dict__` in your first implementation, which is essentially just the attribute name and values in `class Identity`. It is as simple to encode the `{'name': 'Random name'}` wherein everything in the `dict` is `str`.

It's completely different story in your modified code as now you are trying to serialize the `class Identity` itself (which is an instance of type) with its `__dict__`. If you manually lookinto the `__dict__` object into any class
then you will find that `Identity.__dict__` is a `mappingproxy` object that cannot be serialized by your custom encoder.

Long story short, your custom `default` method in the custom encoder tries to serialize something by its `__dict__` attribute. Then in your code example, the encoder first tries to encode the `class Identity` by using its `__dict__` which is a `mappingproxy`. Since the `mappingproxy` is not numbers/str or a list/tuple of them, it will keep trying to encode the `mappingproxy` by further reading its `__dict__`. Because `mappingproxy` does not have `__dict__`, your encoder eventually fails.

Comment: just to add, the "quick" solution here is probably to just `return dict(obj.__dict__)`